# Finding large palindromic primes in the decimal expansion of pi

Tags: number-theory, pi, decimal-expansion, palindrome

I'm trying to complete a coding challenge that involves finding large palindromic primes in the decimal expansion of $\pi$. I'm at the second stage of this challenge, which asks me to find the first palindromic prime of $21$ digits in the decimal expansion of $\pi$. The first stage was finding the first $9$-digit palindromic prime, which is $318272813$, and starts at the $129078$-th digit, not counting the beginning "3." of the expansion "3.1415...". I'm looking for ways to solve this which don't involve brute force/lookup tables.

The way I solved the first one was by the dumbest possible solution: look at the number formed from digits $1$ through $9$ and check if it is a palindromic prime - if not, look at the number formed from digits $2$ through $10$ and check again... so on and so on, until we get the desired palindromic prime and stop this process. There has gotta be a smarter way to go about this though. The way I solved the first stage does not scale.

I had some other potential smarter solutions, but I think they're not gonna help me much either: there are 90 billion palindromes of 21 digits. We can go through all of them and make a list of the prime ones and then look for them in the decimal expansion (noting also that right off the bat we can rule out 50 billion of them because they gotta start/end with either a $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$). I think this might be a faster way than the raw brute force I described previously but I'm not sure, and this is pretty dumb too.

Does anyone have anything else in mind that can help?

Comment: Heuristics suggest there are $2\times10^9$ palindromic primes with $21$ digits, meaning we might expect to need to check $5\times10^{11}$ digits of $\pi$ (give or take an order of magnitude) to find the first success. That puts a lower bound on the number of computations (I believe), since I can't see how to look for successes without listing all the digits. Are you sure your first solution really is that dumb? (Search for palindromes as a first filter, which is computationally easy, and then do primality tests—only about $50$ or so should be needed heuristically.)

Comment: so if you already know how to quickly identify primes and calculate the digits of $\pi$ then if there is no connection between the digits of $\pi$, palindromes and primes the the problem is how to find palindromes in a sequence of random digits. This is not a mathematical problem.

Comment: can you describe what you are doing when you "look at the number formed from digits 1 through 9 and check if it is a palindromic prime"

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! But could you elaborate on how heuristics lead us to those numbers? I'd appreciate it. I called my solution dumb because it's the first, most naive thing one can think of

Comment: @miracle173 sure. For example, digits $1$ through $9$ are $314159265$. That's not a palindrome (so we don't even need to check whether it's a prime number), so the next step of the process is to check digits $2$ through $10$, which corresponds to the number $141592653$, which is not a palindrome either, so we check digits $3$ through $11$, and so on...

Comment: The first heuristic I'm referring to is the prime number theorem, which (slightly but helpfully simplified here) says that the proprtion of $k$-digit numbers that are prime is $\frac1{\ln(10^k)}$. The second is just the expectation of a geometric random variable—if success happens $1$ in $N$ times, then the expected number of trials needed to get a success is $N$.

Comment: It can even be difficult to find any palindromic string in $\pi$ with length $21$ (of course there might be some known ones considering how awfully many digits of $\pi$ have been calculated). And then we still need some luck that it happens to be a prime number. Of course there is no way to solve this without going through the digits of $\pi$